# android, check url is reachable to download stuff

Tags: java, android, url, download

i need a piece of code to check whether is my url reachable to download a pdf file.
here is my own attemp:

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
            try {
                //this is piece of code i use for check url reachable, not working atm.
                if(InetAddress.getByName(fileUrl).isReachable(10000) && !fileName.contains(".pdf")){
                    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
                    File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, documentActivity.getString(R.string.pdf_file_store_folder));
                    folder.mkdir();

                    File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

                    try{
                        pdfFile.createNewFile();
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

this is piece of code in my async task...  my downloader class all working good. i just need one line to check to see if my url is reachable or not...

and the obove code doesnt really work..
please help with some example code. thx

Comment: you could first simply call the url and check the header request. That is what is basically done first

Comment: if it is not reachable an exception will be probably thrown. In any other case you have to check for the Http response code

Comment: that url i use for testing, it is 100% valid, but the code just not download it, it evaluate as false

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the checking part, try this out

```
URL url = new URL(file_url);
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 int code = connection.getResponseCode();

    if(code == 200) {
    // reachable
    } else {
    }
```

Comment: Worked great! I used this to avoid the google app engine client to timeout, since it takes much longer the this little snipplet. :-)